# Stack 3 divs on top of 2 divs inverted pyramid responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am lost trying to stack 5 equal width divs, 3 on top of 2 divs (inverted pyramid, responsively using 2 rows).

I can float 3 divs and 2 divs on two rows all equal width, but the evenly spaced inverted pyramid (responsively) has quickly exploded my minimal CSS brain.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

[Designers vision of the 3 divs stacked on 2 divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJUH1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:inline-block;` instead of floating and aligning to the center. 2 divs should be in a separate container, 3 divs - in another container, one below another. Use `text-align:center;` for each container.

Answer (score 0):

No need for rows. You can do it with `inline-block`s that occupy 33.33% of parent width and are aligned to the center:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, veniam.</div><div class="child">Quisquam architecto, deleniti aperiam ipsam nisi ullam molestiae consequatur optio.</div><div class="child">Quod ad excepturi dolore sed earum impedit, nesciunt aliquid totam.</div><div class="child">Nemo repudiandae delectus deserunt molestiae temporibus modi inventore voluptates. Officiis.</div><div class="child">Quidem autem quae tempore possimus vel commodi architecto, similique tempora.</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3da5tpgn/

**Caveat:** The notorious HTML space can cause issues, you must remove the whitespaces between tags for this to work properly, or use Flexbox:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, nulla.</div>
  <div class="child">Neque doloribus, quasi nobis sint nesciunt. Quod incidunt, vel laudantium!</div>
  <div class="child">Dicta similique quasi inventore, obcaecati quia repellendus odit quam reiciendis?</div>
  <div class="child">Eum esse delectus adipisci pariatur enim, quasi sed odit optio.</div>
  <div class="child">Ea, amet. Ipsam sapiente harum quaerat repudiandae nobis, impedit non.</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/4w46vva9/

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-4">Text 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Text 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Text 3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Text 4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Text 5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not accurate.

Comment: @Aziz It looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, now it looks good (after your edit) anyway, since you're suggesting bootstrap - why not just add `col-md-offset-3` to 4th `div` instead of creating empty divs? they seem unneccessary - see demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/a64yqjt9/

Comment: @Aziz That is also an option.